# Появление дочернего элемента при наведении мышкой на родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как показать дочерний элемент, когда навожу мышкой на его родителя? Пытаюсь как-то так:

```
jQuery(".works-item").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(".item-btn").stop().slideToggle(500);
});
jQuery(".works-item").mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(".item-btn").stop().slideToggle(500);
});
```

Догадываюсь, что через `this` нужно, но не знаю куда именно поместить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как мне показать дочерний элемент, если я навожу мышкой на его родителя?

Можно на CSS:

```css
.child {
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>
  <p>Родительский контейнер</p>
  <hr/>
  <div class=child>
    Дочерний контейнер
  </div>
</div>
```

---

С анимацией:

```css
div {text-align: center;}

.parent {
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-color: silver;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>
  <p>Родительский контейнер</p>
  <div class=child>
    Дочерний контейнер
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вопросе по *Jquery* заплюсован ответ по css. Шедеврально.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, оптимальный способ - как показал @vp_arth, с помощью CSS. А если необходимо именно с помощью jQuery, то так:

```js
jQuery(".works-item").hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".item-btn").slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.works-item {
  background: green
}

.item-btn {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='works-item'>works-item<div class='item-btn'>item-btn</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы хотите это:

```
$(".works-item").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".item-btn").stop().slideToggle(500);
});
$(".works-item").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".item-btn").stop().slideToggle(500);
});
```